# Users See All XenApp Autocreated Session Printers

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, citrix, xenapp

Small farm running Windows Server 2008 x64 and XenApp 5 with the latest hotfix rollup. The users are standard users, but for whatever reason they see all of the auto-created session printers. Initially, everyone was a local admin, but this was taken away quite some time ago.

Is it due to this or something else? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be that the users were previously admins, even though they aren't now. When I completely delete and recreate their profile they can no longer see all of the autocreated printers.

New users also don't have the problem since they were never admins.